# How to remove white border on my custom dialog in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I created my **custom dialog**:

```
//generate dialog view
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.warning_dialog, null);

//create dialog instance
Dialog warningDlg = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomAlertDialog); //my dialog style
warningDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
warningDlg.setContentView(dialogView);
warningDlg.show();
```

As you see above, when I create my dialog instance, I use my own **style** named "`CustomAlertDialog`", which is like following:

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_dialog_bg</item>
</style>
```

Things are working well except that I got **white border** on my dialog window when showing on **Android 2.3.3** device, **how can I remove the white border with my above codes?**

Comment: Oh...nobody can help me?